# VHDL extract constant from entity

Tags: generics, vhdl, constants, latency

My VHDL designs usually contain a decent level of hierarchical "blocks" (entities): a sub-block is made up of multiple sub-blocks that's made up of multiple sub-blocks, etc.

It's very common for me to have to latency match the outputs of internal-blocks before driving the outputs of a given block. When I change the internal blocks and they end up with different latencies, I have to manually re-calculate how to compensate the neighboring block's latencies. If the update affects the given block's overall latency, I then have to repeat the process in any higher level block containing the given block.

It would be much simpler if a block could "tell" the calling entity what its latency is and have these compensations calculated automatically.

Is there a nifty way to do this? Something like a generic-output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right and general solution is to make a package for each sub-module, like `mdl_sub_pkg`, with a constant of the latency in that sub-module.  Then make a package for the enclosing module, like `mdl_pkg`, and use the constant from the `mdl_sub_pkg` package to calculate the latency that the enclosing module should generate.  Finally use the `mdl_pkg` in the enclosing module, and generate the latency based on the calculated constant in the `mdl_pkg`.  Remember to include test of the latency constants in the verification.

An alternative and dubious solution is to make an output port (as alternative to the non-existing output generic) on the sub-module and assign this with a constant that matches the latency in the sub-module.  The enclosing modules may then use the output port from the sub-modules to calculate the resulting latency for that module.  However, whether this solution works and generates minimum size synthesized design depends heavily on how the latency compensation is implemented, and on how the synthesis tool handles elaboration and reduction of design parts containing constants.  In certain situations it may be a workable solution and a nice trick, but it is not a general applicable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to pass in your expected(or desired) latency as a generic.

Internally, assert actual latency = generic latency and fail if wrong.

Or insert pipe stages if actual latency < generic latency until they match, and assert/fail if actual latency > generic latency, and do nothing if they are equal. This gives an easy way of synchronising pipelines from the top level.